# Get value from hash param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

At this time I have this field in the partial "_form.html.erb"

```
<% Pregunta.where("subpoll_id = ?", s.id).each.with_index do |i, index| %>
    <tr>
    <td>
            <%= f.input :descripcion, 
            :label => false, 
            :error => false,
            :input_html => {
            :name     => "pregunta[]",
            :class    =>'form-control input-sm',
            :value    => "#{i.descripcion}",
            :readonly => true,
            :style    => "
                border:hidden;
                background-color:white;"} %>
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
        <%= f.input :respuesta,
                :collection => Respuesta.where("pregunta_id = ?", i.id),
            :label      => false,
            :error      => false,
            :input_html => {
            :class =>'form-control input-sm',
            :name => "respuesta[]"} %>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

So as you see I get a hash with this `:name => "respuesta[]"` because that field repeats in the form depending of the number of "preguntas"

From my controller I'm getting the information this way

```
@respuesta  = params[:respuesta]
```

And my question is:
How can I get an especific value of this hash for save it in a column table and for compare it with another's values

thanks for your help

Comment: What  params in controller you are getting only params[:respuesta]?

Comment: Yes, At this moment I just need to use this params[:respuesta]

Comment: what do you mean get? `params[:respuesta][:param_you_need]`?

Comment: I mean that @respuesta = params[:respuesta] is a hash, so I need to receive in a variable or something the value of one of those elements with an index(position) and then I can save it in the column table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting identity less array of values, you can give identity to each value using following minor change that will be posted as array of hashes:

```
<% Pregunta.where("subpoll_id = ?", s.id).each.with_index do |i, index| %>
  .
  <%= f.input :respuesta,
    .
    :name => "respuesta[#{i.id}]"} %>
    .
```

You'll get params in the form:

```
{respuesta: [{pregunta_id: respuesta_value}, {pregunta_id: respuesta_value} .. ]}
```

Later, you can get specific values by:

```
params[:respuesta].each do |key_val|
  Pregunta.find(key_val[0]).update_attribute('respuesta', key_val[1])
end
```

If you need further level of specification for the values of respuesta, you can do something like this:

```
<%= f.input :respuesta, :collection => Respuesta.
  where("pregunta_id = ?", i.id).collect{|r| [r.val, r.id] }, ...
```

Later you can get specific respuesta value by:

```
params[:respuesta][<pregunta_id>][<respuesta_id>]
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

playing around with the following may help:

```
@respuesta.each_with_index do |(respuesta_key, respuesta_value), index|
   puts "Respuesta: #{index}" 
   puts "Key: #{respuesta_key}"
   puts "Value: #{respuesta_value}"
end
```